# Pyspark job freezes with too many vcpus

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

**TLDR**: I have a pyspark job that finishes in 10 minutes when I run it in a ec2 instance with 16 vcpus but freezes out (it doesn't fail, just never finishes) if I use an instance with over 20 vcpus. I have tried everything I could think of and I just don't know why this happens.

**Full story**:

I have around 200 small pyspark jobs that for a matter of costs and flexibility I execute using aws batch with spark dockers instead of EMR. Recently I decided to experiment around the best configuration for those jobs and I realized something weird: a job that finished quickly (around 10 minutes) with 16 vcpus or less would just never end with 20 or more (I waited for 3 hours). First thing I thought is that it could be a problem with batch or the way ecs-agents manage the task, so I tried running the docker in an ec2 directly and had the same problem. Then I thought the problem was with the docker image, so I tried creating a new one:

- First one used with spark installed as per AWS glue compatible version (https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/glue-1.0/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8.tgz)
- New one was ubuntu 20 based with spark installed from the apache mirror (https://apache.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/spark/spark-$SPARK_VERSION/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop$HADOOP_VERSION.tgz)

Same thing happened. Then I decided the problem was with using docker at all, so I installed everything directly in the ec2, had the same result. Tried changing spark version, also the same thing happened. Thought it could be a problem with hardware blocking too many threads, so I switched to an instance with AMD, nothing changed. Tried modifying some configurations, memory amount used by driver, but it always has the same result: 16 vcpus it work, more than it, it stops.

Other details:

- According to the logs it seems to always stop at the same point: a parquet read operation on s3, but the parquet file is super small (> 1mb) so I don't think that is the actual problem.
- After that it still has logs sometimes but nothing really useful, just "INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator".
- I use s3a to read the files from s3.
- I don't get any errors or spark logs.

I appreciate any help on the matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop using the Hadoop 2.7 binaries. They are woefully obsolete, especially for S3 connectivity. replace all the hadoop 2.7 artifacts with Hadoop 2.8 ones, or, preferably, Hadoop 3.2 or later, with the consistent dependencies.
2. set `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.experimental.fadvise" to random.

If you still see problems, see if you can replicate them on hadoop 3.3.x, and if so: file a bug.

(advice correct of 2021-03-9; the longer it stays in SO unedited, the less it should be believed)

Comment: do you know the proper version of hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk-bundle to use with hadoop 3.2? I tried it with hadoop 3.2 and hadoop-aws-3.2.2.jar and got a "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService, int, boolean)'" which is likely a version mismatch.

Comment: for who else may need this: everything worked fine for hadoop 3.2 using aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.874.jar and hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar

Comment: good to hear. you need an exact x.y.x match between all of hadoop-*, just as you need within the spark-* jars; they are essentially each one single product release and are not designed for mix-and-match. Both teams will treat all bug reports there as INVALID